# Confusing with "CGRectMake" coordinate

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uikit, cocos2d-iphone

From the following code

```
// yPos = 0, width = 100, height = 150
[imagesMutable enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(UIScrollView verticalScroll, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
  [verticalScroll addSubView:[UIImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPos, width, height)]]
  // some code
  yPos += (height + 15)
}];
```

Let's say, if imagesMutable got 3 objects. And as I read from somewhere that CGRectMake is using cartesian coordinate (x = 0, y = 0 will be bottom left). So, it should be

```
[verticalScroll addSubView:[UIImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 150)]]
[verticalScroll addSubView:[UIImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 165, 100, 150)]]
[verticalScroll addSubView:[UIImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 330, 100, 150)]]
```

This should mean that

```
First CGRectMake should has bottom left at (0, 0) and top right at (100, 150)
Second CGRectMake should has bottom left at (0, 165) and top right at (100, 315) 
Third CGRectMake should has bottom left at (0, 330) and top right at (100, 480)
```

Then, the order of images from top to bottom should be 3 -> 2 -> 1 comparing to the imagesMutable's objects ordering (1 -> 2 -> 3)

But why, it appearing in order of 1 -> 2 -> 3 as same as imagesMutable's objects ordering when I launch the app? Am I missing something?

Comment: For UIKit the origin is top left, for cocos2d it's bottom left

Comment: By that, you mean, CGRectMake is UIKit? (I'm starting iOS development for just 2 weeks, still confusing)

Comment: CG functions are CoreGraphics. (0,0) i.e. the origin is different between frameworks. CGRectMake(0,0,100,150) itself is just a struct with origin = CGPoint(0,0) (the origin) and is independent. Where this origin is depends on the framework. You can use the same rect with (0,0) in both frameworks but they could mean different positions on the screen.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

(0,0) is not bottom-left but top-left.

The view has inverted y coordinates, so that y increases as you move down the screen.

[image]